# neo4j browser being slooooow

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I have grown used to the neo4j browser being slow. I mean really slow. If I make a query to the Movies database it takes maybe 15 seconds for it to show the result.
It has bugged me, and was one of the reasons I bailed last time I looked at neo4j. "Too slow" i thought.
But now I'm watching a movie about neo4j and in that demo, results comes back almost immediately.

I have a new install. Not changed anything. Total beginner.

Is this a known issue, or am I the only one in the world?
What can I try to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

neo4j is not very different from other databases beside the unique graph functionality it offers , if you have the correct indexes created as much memory you have as faster the database will be , afcourse storage performance is important , if you have aggregation or sorting queries CPU is needed.  Some good starting point you have here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/memory-configuration/